# Facebook Register Plugin - Form submitting even though validation fails?

Tags: facebook, forms, validation, oauth, xfbml

I'm using the Facebook Registration Plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) to register users for our site. The problem is I can't seem to get custom validation working and was wondering whether it's a mistake on my part or something wrong with Facebook.

This is the XFBML code that I'm using:

```
<fb:registration
    fields="[{'name':'name'},
             {'name':'email'}, 
             {'name':'password','description':'Enter a password','type':'text'}]"
    redirect-uri="http://local.dev"
    onvalidate="validateFacebookRegistrationForm">
</fb:registration>
```

and I have a global function called validateFacebookRegistrationForm which has the following code in it:

```
function validateFacebookRegistrationForm(form) {
    errors = {};

    if (form.password == "") {
        errors.password = "No Password Entered";
    }

    return errors;
}
```

I would expect hitting the register button on the form would do nothing and the validation message would show up... instead I get a popup like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcHaj.jpg

Once the popup is closed, the form is validated ... and the error message shows. Clicking register again will not submit the form until the errors have been fixed - which is the how the form should behave in the first instance!

Comment: FBML has been depricated - you should not use it.

Comment: How else could I do validation of the fields? From the docs: "If you want to add validation to any of your fields during registration, you must use the XFBML version of the plugin, since the iframe can't do cross domain communication" >> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/.

Comment: Yep, I've just googled this ... sorry I'm new to developing with Facebook! Now that we've addressed I've just got the wrong terminology (initial post updated) - any idea why the above isn't working

Comment: @csdev86 I am seeing the same issue now. Did you find a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Registration plugin does not client-side validate until AFTER the user has pressed "Register" and then in the popup pressed "Continue". Then, it will do the "client-side" validation... it really doesn't make sense to go in that order but that's how it seems to be.

Your code is fine.